# How to display data on the Datagrid from the dataset using db2 DB

Tags: stored-procedures, datagrid, dataset, db2, vb.net-2010

I solved the problem with the data not displaying and have corrected the code below.

I need to populate the dataset with the values returned in a stored procedure in db2. I have written a some code which connected to the DB and seems to execute the SP and am populating the dataset but am not find able to figure out how to display the data from the dataset to the grid. Right now it is blank an no data in the grid.

```
Imports IBM.Data
Imports IBM.Data.DB2
Imports IBM.Data.DB2.DB2DataReader

'cs is the connection string you create in your application.

Dim conn As DB2Connection = New DB2Connection(cs)
conn.Open()


Dim trans As IDbTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
Dim cmd As IDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
Dim procName As String = "SP_Name"
cmd.Transaction = trans
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.CommandText = procName
Dim db2da As New DB2DataAdapter
Dim db2ds As New DataSet
db2da.SelectCommand = cmd
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
db2da.Fill(db2ds, "Tab1")

Dim introwcount As Integer = db2ds.Tables("Tab1").Rows.Count
Dim intColumncount As Integer = db2ds.Tables("Tab1").Columns.Count

dgvData.DataSource = db2ds.Tables("Tab1")
```

Appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a DB2Command instead of IDbTransaction? That's how I know to do it, but your requirements may be different than mine.

```
Dim conn As DB2Connection = New DB2Connection(cs)
Dim cmd As New DB2Command()
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.CommandText = procName
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim rdr AS DB2DataReader = Nothing

Try
     conn.Open()
     rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     dgvData.DataSource = rdr
     dgvData.DataBind()
     rdr.Close()
Catch ex As DB2Exception
     ...
Finally
     conn.Close()
End Try
```